# Strange compilation error on reference passing argument to function

Tags: c++, reference, compiler-errors

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void mysize(int &size, int size2);
int main()
{
    int *p;
    int val;
    p = &val;
    cout << p;
    mysize(&val, 20); // Error is pointed here!
}

void mysize(int &size, int size2)
{
    cout << sizeof(size);
    size2 = size2 + 6000;
    cout << size2;
}
```

Here's the error output from GCC:

> In function 'int main()':
>   Line 10: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from a temporary of type 'int*'
>   compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

What does that imply? I do not understand the error message ... invalid initialization of a non-constant? I declared the prototype function above with two parameters to take, one a reference of an integer and one just an integer value itself. I passed the reference of the int (see line 10), yet this error keeps being thrown at me. Also, how is it "temporarily a pointer"?

What is the issue?

Comment: So, the function expects a *reference* to an integer parameter, as you said it yourself. Why then are you attempting to pass a *pointer* to integer argument to it? References and pointers are not the same and are not interchangeable.

Comment: I am passing _&val_, which is a **reference**.

Comment: Your insistence that a pointer is a reference is not going to change the C++ language.

Comment: @Grewdrewgoo Goobergabbsoen: False. `&val` in `mysize(&val, 20)` is an application of address-of operator `&` to variable `val`. The result is a **pointer** to `val`. Where did you get the idea that `&val` is a reference?

Comment: I think the OP may be referring to the formal parameter declaration?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: No. In the comments to the other answers OP made it very clear that he believes that that specific `&val` in the argument list of the function call `mysize(&val, 20)` is a "reference".

Comment: That's not what it says here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: @AndreyT: Yeah, OK, I give up :-S

Comment: There is this general feeling that cplusplus.com isn't very good. I don't use it, so I didn't have a strong opinion on that. But that particular article looks pretty bad in the way it confuses basic C++ terminology.

Comment: Did you see the link? That site is where I learned most C++, and you are telling me that the site is wrong when it is dedicated to C++?

Comment: @Grewdrewgoo Goobergabbsoen: There's nothing at cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers to support your assertions.

Comment: @GrewdrewgooGoobergabbsoen, you need a better source. cplusplus.com is notoriously bad.

Comment: I'm starting to recognize the familiar hand. I strongly suspect that this is the same troll as the one from a few days ago... whatever that name was I don't remember.

Comment: Show me a better source and **prove** me wrong then. I showed my sources.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/

Comment: Your code is right. We are all wrong and that compiler error is a bug.

Comment: @GrewdrewgooGoobergabbsoen http://ideone.com/s680G5

Comment: Placing the & in front of the variable gets a pointer to a variable.  Placing an & in front of a declaration makes the declaration a reference.  Your compile will succeed if you remove the & from the call to mysize.  The compiler will automatically produce the reference for you. The error is that you are passing a pointer to a function that wants a reference.

Answer (score 4):

`val` is an `int`, `&val` is the address of `val`, which is a pointer to an `int`. Your function expects a reference. You need to call it like this

```
mysize(val, 20);
```

and change the signature to

```
void mysize(const int &size, int size2);
```

or, even better,

```
void mysize(int size, int size2);
```

because you are not modifying `size`.

Comment: What are you talking about? &val is a reference, and I am passing &val as the first argument to the void function preceeding.

Comment: @GrewdrewgooGoobergabbsoen What are *you* talking about? `&val` is a pointer to `int`.

Comment: I passed the reference. &val is a reference. *val is a pointer.

Comment: Who said I want a const?

Comment: @GrewdrewgooGoobergabbsoen: You need to start talking in more precise language. Loose fragments don't cut it. When you declare `void f(int * p)`, that function takes one formal parameter of type `int *`, but it's not the case that "`*p` is a pointer" -- that doesn't even make sense (rather, within the function body, `*p` is an *int*!). On the other hand, when you have a variable `int n;`, then `&n` is the address of `n`, and the address has type `int *`.

Comment: I really don't understand the semantics of your post. How can a reference parameter take an argument of a pointer when a pointer and reference is different?

Comment: @Grewdrewgoo Goobergabbsoen: *Declaration* `int &val` *declares* a reference. Meanwhile, *expression* `&val` has absolutely noting to do with references. The same way, *declaration* `int *ptr` declares a pointer, while expression `*ptr` *dereferences* a pointer, producing an `int` value.

Comment: @GrewdrewgooGoobergabbsoen Please use a language where they don't use `&` to mean more than one thing.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the address of an integer to `mysize` which expects an integer argument to be passed by reference. Change the call to this:

```
mysize(val, 20); //remove &
```

Comment: I tried that, and I get this error: In function 'int main()':
Line 7: error: 'val' declared as reference but not initialized
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Comment: No. You would need that if the function expected a pointer

Comment: No, when you use reference you simply pass the variable name.

Comment: I am passing a reference, so I am using an ampersand. Or do I have C/C++ wrong here?

Comment: You need to read a chapter on C++ functions. Don't confuse C and C++. They are not the same language despite what you may have been told.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: @GrewdrewgooGoobergabbsoen Wow, that link is so seriously wrong. Thanks for bringing it up. It seems designed to muddle things up, because *reference* has a very specific meaning in C++, and it is not what the article implies.

Comment: How can the very tutorial on that site be wrong? Are you joking now by telling me that everything I learned about syntax and C++ is wrong?

Comment: @GrewdrewgooGoobergabbsoen Well the important point is the subtle difference in terminology: "reference operator" vs. "reference". These are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between pointers and references. For references, imagine that the compiler does "take the address" and "dereference" for you, you don't have to (and mustn't) do it manually. Also, note the `&`-operator's different meanings. Some Examples:

```
int a = 5;
int *pa = &a; // take address of a, store it in pa
int &ra = a; // define ra as a reference to a

// Function taking reference to long and pointer to int
void foo(long& a, int* b);

// Call it like this:
long myLong = 100;
int myInt = 10;
foo(myLong, &myInt);
```

So for a reference, you don't need to use the address operator `&` (it's done implicitely), whereas you need it for a pointer.